# Upgrade glassfish 3.1.1 to 3.1.2.2 with pre-downloaded patches

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I've a problem on upgrade glassfish from the current version 3.1.1 to 3.1.2.2.
Is anyone know other than the Update Tool, which I believe will required to have Internet access in order to download latest patches and perform glassfish upgrade.

Is there anyway to have a pre-downloaded patches that can allowed me to just run the upgrade on the target server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup GF 3.1.2.2 on a computer with Internet, download patches, etc. Then you remove domain folder (usually domain1), pack the rest using your best archival tool. And move that thing to a target server, unpack there and copy domain folder from old GF.